# Spring JMS TextMessage write to PDF

Tags: spring, pdf-generation, jms, websphere, byte

I have a default Spring message listener running.

When the onMessage hits, it comes in as TextMessage (NOT BytesMessage)

How do I write that into a PDF file?

I think there is some issue with my code below...so it writes to the file, but the pdf will not open...

```
    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        try {
            //System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());

            TextMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage)message;
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(txtMessage.getText().getBytes("UTF8"));

            String outStr=bais.toString();

            File newFile=new File("D:\\document.pdf");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            int data;
            while((data=bais.read())!=-1)
            {
            char ch = (char)data;
            fos.write(ch);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
```

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using a pdf specific API to create/update a pdf file. I would highly recommend [iText](http://itextpdf.com/index.php). A pdf file is not simply a stream of bytes. A lot of things are involved and you have to consider font, page size, starting X and Y coordinates, direction of text, adding new pages, tabulat structure or free style and list goes on.

There are a lot of code examples on the site that will get you started. Here is a simplified snippet of adding text in a pdf file using iText API:

```
    try {
    ... 

    BufferedInputStream bis = new  BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pdfFile));

    ...  

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bis);

    /* outs could be any output stream */

    stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,outs);

    ... /* removed the code to get current page */

    PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(currentPage);
    over.beginText();
    over.setFontAndSize(myFont, myFontSize);
    over.setTextMatrix(xPoint, yPoint);
    over.showText("Add this text");
    over.endText();
    ... /* removed code to adjust x and y coordinate and add page if needed */
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        stamper.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {/* handle exception */}

    try {
        outs.flush();
        outs.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {/* handle exception */}

}
```